# How to add DispatchQueue delay in swift while loop?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a delay inside a while loop. I'm fairly new to this and it's currently just not working. It never fires even once with the dispatch delay, but if I remove the delay it fires repeatedly.

Basically what I'm doing is checking if the velocity of nodes in a SKScene is still moving, if they're still moving, don't end the game. But once they've slowed down, end the game.

```
func RemainingNodeCheck (complete:() -> Void) {

    CountVelocites()

    if (IdleVelocity.max()!.isLess(than: 1.0)) {
        complete()
    } else {

    print("Velocity too high, begin wait...")

      while !(IdleVelocity.max()?.isLess(than: 1.0))! {

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)) {
                    print("Second passed")
                    self.CountVelocites()
                }

            if (IdleVelocity.max()!.isLess(than: 1.0)) {
                break
            }
        }

        print("Velocity Calmed down")
        complete()
    }

}
```

I believe this might be something to do with threads? Or it's actually just telling the delay to begin waiting for one second so many times that it never gets to call?

**UPDATE:** I would use a timer, but the RemaingNodeCheck is being called from another part and it's waiting for RemainingNodeCheck to send back complete()

Comment: "Or it's actually just telling the delay to begin waiting for one second so many times that it never gets to call?" Yes, you are looping forever and so the `asyncAfter` never has a chance to re-enter. But the whole construct is wrong, so just drop it and use a timer instead (or something more appropriate to what you are trying to do).

Comment: Unrelated, but, as a matter of convention, method/variable names should start with lowercase letters. Only type names and the like start with uppercase letters.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm a bit of a noob, but could you be a bit more specific @Rob ? Are you saying the variables like IdleVelocity should never start with a capital but my custom functions can?

Comment: I’m suggesting that `remainingNodeCheck` and `countVelocities` should both start with lowercase letters. And, assuming that `IdleVelocity` is some variable, then that, too, should be `idleVelocity`. Only class names, struct names, enum names, protocol names, etc., should start with uppercase letters. Methods, properties, variables, enumeration cases, etc., should start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never want to "wait". But you can set up a repeating timer that checks for some condition, and if so, calls the `complete` closure (invalidating the timer, if you want). E.g.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var idleVelocity: ...

    weak var timer: Timer?

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    func startCheckingVelocity(complete: @escaping () -> Void) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
            guard let self = self, let maxVelocity = self.idleVelocity.max() else { return }

            if maxVelocity < 1 {
                timer.invalidate()
                complete()
                return
            }

            print("velocity too high...")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This appears to perform exactly as needed. The only thing I needed to change was to make sure to add the CountVelocites() func in there (otherwise the maxVelocity would always stay the same). It also had to be added in after the timer section. Could you explain how this works? I don't understand how the timer just gets the code beneath it to repeat? (I thought a timer had to have a selector with that whole @objc func thing?)

Comment: The `Timer` with the `target` and `selector` was the old pattern, but in iOS 10, they introduced this closure-based pattern of [`scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:repeats:block:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer), where you just pass a closure (or using “trailing closure” syntax, just provide it after). So it’s similar to the `target`/`selector` rendition, but a little more concise, using closures...